# How can one figure out what the open sets of a quotient space are, rather than just verifying them?

Tags: general-topology

In Munkres, he gives this example (example 4 in section 22) of a quotient map and space:

> Let $X$ be the closed unit ball $\{x \times y \mid x^2 + y^2 \leq 1\}$ in $\mathbb R^2$, and let $X^\ast$ be the partition consisting of all one-point sets $\{x \times y\}$ for which $x^2 + y^2 < 1$, along with the set $S^1 = \{x \times y \mid x^2 + y^2 = 1\}$ ...

with image:

[image]

The definition of open sets in the quotient space (with respect to the quotient map $p: X \rightarrow Y$) is: "a set $U \subset Y$ is open in the quotient space if and only if its complete preimage $p^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$".

I understand *why* the open sets in $X^\ast$ are what they are in this example; the shaded areas are the saturated open sets in $X$ that map to the open sets of $X^\ast$.

What I'm wondering is: this definition seems to tell you how to *verify* that a set in the quotient space is open (see what maps to it from the original space and check that that's open). But it doesn't tell me how to *find* the open sets of the quotient space.

In this simple example, it was easy enough to try and map an arbitrary open set of $X$, look at its image, and then try taking the complete pre-image of that, and noticing that it's not open in $X$ anymore, and then adjusting accordingly. But it seems like it would be hard in general.

Is there some more general way of finding these open sets in the quotient space, rather than just verifying ones we already know about?